# C# WPF Window with 'out' for one of the parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, constructor

My problem is I have a variable that I need the window to send back, so I am using out to accomplish this. Here is an example of the constructor for the WPF window.

```
    public CustomYesNo(out bool FormFilled)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormFilled = false;
    }
```

The problem i'm having is I want it so one of the other methods in the class will be able to modify the FormFilled variable that gets sent back to the calling class like below.

```
    private void Button_Yes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FormFilled = true;
        Close();
    }
```

Obviously the Button_Yes_Click method does not have access to the FormFilled variable, and I am trying to figure out how I could possible change the value of the FormFilled variable from this method since this variable is only in the constructor's scope. Is what I am trying to do possible using 'out' or do I need to go another route?

Comment: Why not use FormFilled as a property in the window and call the window as a dialog then fetch the property back?

Comment: I guess I could do it that way I just didn't really think about that.

Comment: best not to re-invent the wheel. the .DialogResult property may also be worth a look

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Wobbles!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern

Calling Method:

```
class foo
{
    public void bar()
    {
        DialogForm myDialogForm = new DialogForm();
        myDialogForm.ShowDialog();
        if (myDialogForm.DialogResult)
        {
            //Its true
        }
    }

}
```

Form window:

```
public partial class DialogForm : Window
{
    public DialogForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void submitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.DialogResult = true;
    }
}
```

The calling method in WPF is slightly different for checking the result:

```
bool? result = myDialogForm.ShowDialog();
if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
```